# Convert json array to character list esql

Tags: arrays, json, ibm-integration-bus, cardinality, extended-sql

I have the following json syntax

```
{
"PRINTER": "P123", 
"ID_INPUT": "111046", 
"IDCOUNT": 3, 
"TIME": "",
"IDLIST": [{ID_IN": "111046"},{"ID_IN": "111047"}, {"ID_IN": "111048"}]
}
```

My goal is to iterate over IDLIST and create a character string like "111046;111047;111048" in esql. But I have problems on processing the json. I tried:

```
DECLARE c       INTEGER;   -- cardinality
DECLARE i       INTEGER 0; -- index
DECLARE idlist  CHARACTER '';

-- find cardinality
SET c = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.JSON.Data.IDLIST[]); -- Q1
            
-- iterate over IDLIST
WHILE i < c DO
  -- build new data structure
  SET idlist = idlist || InputRoot.JSON.Data.IDLIST[i] || ';'; -- Q2
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

- Q1: Is it possible to get the cardinality this way?
- Q2: Can I write my data structure like this?
- Q3: Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't use the [tag:esql] tag — use one of [tag:embedded-sql], [tag:extended-sql] and [tag:entity-sql].  I am confident what you're using is not 'embedded-sql'; I'm not sure what it is that you are using, though.

Comment: It is extended-sql tag i.e. esql used in a tool called IBM Integration Bus(IIB). I have updated the right tags to the question, should be visible once approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cardinality function is not necessary to get the desired string value. Also, cardinality is an expensive(processor intensive) function in IIB esql.

```
    DECLARE idlist CHAR '';
    FOR PTR AS InputRoot.JSON.Data.IDLIST.Item[] DO
        SET idlist = idlist || PTR.ID_IN  || ';'    ;           
    END FOR;
    
    SET idlist = TRIM(TRAILING ';' FROM idlist); --This is to get rid of the last ; in the string
```

Comment: @user2663557 - would appreciate if you could tell whether the above answer helped ?

Comment: I will - hopefully I can test it today. Thank you!